# Retrieve users friends for tagging

Tags: iphone, facebook

How does one retrieve a users friends using facebook connect so that a user can tag their friends in a post?

I am using sharekit to post images to a users wall, but I want to also add the option where a user can tag friends in an image before posting.

How does one allow tagging in an iOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Facebook Connect is too lightweight for that; it is designed for fairly simple interactions hosted on 3rd party (non-Facebook) site. I think you will have to build a Facebook App to do what you describe.